# How to get a dropdown to output an array from a database nodejs

Tags: jquery, sql, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to get my web application to display a dropdown list from my database but its not separating the data in separate option tags, i tried following various methods that include a forEach approach but no luck, this is what my code looks like right now which currently displays the database but not in a dropdown list format i would like.

```js
app.js

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var registerRouter = require('./routes/register');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/register', registerRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);

// get PLAYERS for dropdown in 'create a team'
app.get('/getData_players', function(req, res) {

  // connect to the db
  var mysql = require('mysql')
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'mgp'

  });

  connection.connect();
  connection.query('SELECT * from players', function(err, rows, fields) {
    // ensuring to throw something wheter there's an error or not
    if (err) throw err;

    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

      var player = rows[i].player + ' ';

      output = output + player;

    }

    console.log("Connected to player table!");
    res.send(output);
  });
  connection.end();
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
index.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/themes/RED.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Team</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h2>Create a team</h2>

      GK
      <select onclick="getData_players()" id="goal_keeper" />
      <option class="player_data"></option>
      </select>

      RB
      <select id="right_back" /></select>
      CB
      <select id="center_back_1" /></select>
      CB
      <select id="center_back_2" /></select>
      LB
      <select id="left_back" /></select>
      RM
      <select id="right_mid" /></select>
      CM
      <select id="center_mid_1" /></select>
      CM
      <select id="center_mid_2" /></select>
      LM
      <select id="left_mid" /></select>
      ST
      <select id="striker1" /></select>
      ST
      <select id="striker2" /></select>
      <button id="submitTeam" class="ui-btn">Submit Team</button>

      <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b">Logout</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
  </div>

  <!-- SHOW PLAYERS DROPDOWN -->
  <script>
    function getData_players() {

      $.get("/getData_players", function(data) {
        // embed the data into the player select tag
        var x = $(".player_data").html(data);
        //$('<option>').val(1).text('blah');
      });

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `simply not working` Is never a good way to start a question on SO, what exactly is the error, wrong behavior? What is the "format you like"

Comment: Sorry about that, the error is that it doesn't output the data i want in each <option> tag based on the data's length, i want the data to display in the dropdown is separate option tags

Comment: We are talking about `output` variable in `getData_players` function? that should be  one `option` in `select`?

Comment: I am not familiar with your this way of building an app but try this  https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/op6h94bv/1/ In your loop option variable will be made like new select option, if document.querySelector works that is.

Comment: Yes it should be one option, but i want the number of option tags to increase based on the data to the index.ejs recieves from my database

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data and append the options as you iterate on your data array.

```
$.get("/getData_players", function(data) {
        // this snippet will populate data in your right backs 
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('#right_back').append($('<option>', { 
                value: item.player_id,
                text : item.player_name 
            }));
        });

      });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I put your function into my index.ejs but now no data is being recieved from the database and it doesnt display any players, did it work for you?